# Query Neo4j for yearly statistics using timestamps

Tags: timestamp, neo4j, cypher

I was given the task to visualize the feature usage of an application that uses Neo4j as the back end. I want to, for example, visualize how many "Wish" elements were created each year. The  Wish node has a creationDate attribute that saves a timestamp when the element was created.
The output should look like this:

```
Year #Wishes
2000  20 
2001 99
```

...

The best I can currently output is

```
Year          Description
1365431858      "smth"
1365431859      "smth2"
```

...

```
START n = node(0)
MATCH (n)-[:WISH]->(m)
RETURN m.creationDate as Year, m.description as Description
```

How can I group timestamps into years/months? The application is using neo4j 1.8.3

Comment: CASE/WHEN solves this problem in Neo4j 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use just division to extract the year.

Something like:

```
return 1970 + round(m.creationDate / (365.242 * 24 * 3600)), count(m)
```

so in your case it would be 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1.8.3 does not have a native Date type, I don't believe you're going to able to group by the year in a single cypher query.

Here's two approaches to consider:

1) multiple queries with a date range.  So, 2012 *might* look like:

```
MATCH (n)-[:WISH]->(m)
WHERE m.creationDate > '1325376000' AND m.creationDate < '1356998399'
return count(m) as total, '2012' as year
```

might not be the most elegant approach, but it is a solution :)

2) modify the model to include relationships to date info. If all you were looking for is a year relationship, it could be handled pretty quickly. Here's a post discussing that option:

[Modeling dates in Neo4j](http://blog.nigelsmall.com/2012/09/modelling-dates-in-neo4j.html)